# How to activate Discretionary Ligatures by default with "libertinus-otf" package?

Tags: fonts, luatex, ligatures, opentype, libertinus

I am using the package `libertinus-otf` with `LuaLatex`, `MikTeX` and the KOMA-Script document class `scrartcl`.
How do I activate Discretionary Ligatures by default for all fonts?
I have tried many things as `fontscpec`'s `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=Rare}`, but nothing seems to work, both for `Libertinus Serif` and `Libertinus Sans`, and all of their variants (italic, bold, italic-bold etc.)
Here is my minimal working exemple :

```
\documentclass[french]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}

\begin{document}

\subject{1. affichettes}
\title{2. affichettes}
\subtitle{3. affichettes}
\author{4. affichettes}
\date{5. affichettes}
\publishers{6. affichettes}
\maketitle

7. affichettes

\textsf{8. affichettes}

\end{document}
```

I am using the french word "affichettes" (little poster) so we can observe easily the discretionary "tt" and "ch" ligatures with the common "ffi" ligature.

[image: ligatures]

Of course, using `\Ldlig{affichettes}` or `\LDLIG+ affichettes` everywhere works, but this is not a viable solution. Here is what we should get.

[image: wanted result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like when I was using the `defaultfeatures` option, I put an extra space after the `=` symbol:

```
\usepackage[defaultfeatures = {Ligatures = Discretionary}]{libertinus-otf}
```

Without this extra space, it works:

```
\usepackage[defaultfeatures ={Ligatures = Discretionary}]{libertinus-otf}
```

(notice the only difference)

That is a curious behaviour, why is that?
Maybe a futur change to this?

Thanks

Comment: I am aware of that, I was speaking of discretionary ligatures, the `ffi` ligature is a common ligature

Comment: Ah, Isee. It is a bug, will be fixed ...

Comment: It is not a problem with `libertinus-otf`, but a problem with package `xkeyval` which cannot read the arguments properly. Use `\usepackage[defaultfeatures={Ligatures=Discretionary}]{libertinus-otf}` without spaces.